# Code doesn't get upgraded from ANTJS v3 to ANTJS v4

Tags: javascript, antd, ant-design-pro

I am using `ANTJS` for react and it was very simple to use. Now they have upgraded their version 3 to 4. In version 4, the code has been minimized.

Since, I am using ANT JS in all my code which is in version 3. I want to upgrade to v4. ANTJS have provided a tool for migrating code from ANTJS v3 to v4. I used the tool but it doesn't get worked for me.
Here's the Login Page designed in ANTJS v3:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import { LockOutlined, UserOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Form } from '@ant-design/compatible';
import '@ant-design/compatible/assets/index.css';
import { Button, Input, notification, Result } from 'antd';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import context from '../context';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Card, Elevation } from "@blueprintjs/core";
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'

const TITLE = 'PROCESSOR'

const cookies = new Cookies();
class Login extends React.Component{
    static contextType = context;
    state ={ username : "", password : "", loginLoading: false, networkCheck:false }
    async onLogin(){
        this.props.form.validateFields(['username','password'], (err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                if(this.state.username && this.state.password){
                    (async () => {
                        var loginData = new FormData()
                        loginData.set('username',this.state.username)
                        loginData.set('password',this.state.password)
                        this.setState({ loginLoading: true })
                        try{
                            var response = await axios({ method : 'post', url : 'http://localhost:5001/login', data : loginData, });
                            if (response.status === 200 && response.data.success && response.data.token){
                                this.setState({networkCheck:false})
                                cookies.set('loginToken', response.data.token, { path: '/' })
                                this.props.history.push('/');
                            }

                        }
                        catch(err){
                            if(err.message === 'Network Error'){
                                this.setState({networkCheck:true, componentLoading:false})
                                console.log(err.message)
                            }  
                        }
                        this.setState({ loginLoading: false })
                    })(); 
                } 
            }   
        })
    }
    backtoLogin(){
        cookies.remove('loginToken', { path: '/' })
        this.props.history.push('/');
    }
    render(){
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
        return (
            <div style={{display:'flex', backgroundColor:"#809596", height: '100%', justifyContent: 'center',  alignItems: 'center' }}>
                {
                    this.state.networkCheck?
                    <div >
                        <Result
                            status="404"
                            title="404"
                            subTitle="Sorry, Network Error."
                            extra={<Button onClick={this.backtoLogin.bind(this)}  type="primary">Back to Login Page </Button>}
                        />
                    </div>
                    :
                    <div style = {{display:'flex', alignItems:'center',alignContent:'center', justifyContent:'center', height:'100%',width:'100%'}}>
                        <Helmet>
                            <title>{ TITLE }</title>
                        </Helmet>

                        <Card style={{backgroundColor:"#c4ccc6", width:'25%', alignContent:'center' }} elevation={Elevation.TWO}>
                            <div style = {{display:'flex',color:'black', justifyContent:'center', fontSize:'130%', fontFamily:'"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif'}}>Flax Data Processor</div>
                            <hr></hr>
                            <Form.Item   >
                                {getFieldDecorator('username', {

                                    rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please enter Username!', whitespace: true }],
                                    onChange: (event) => { this.setState({ username: event.target.value }) },
                                })(<Input prefix={<UserOutlined style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
                                placeholder="Enter Username"  />)}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <Form.Item  >
                                {getFieldDecorator('password', {
                                    rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please enter Password!', whitespace: true }],
                                    onChange: (event) => { this.setState({ password: event.target.value }) },
                                })(<Input.Password prefix={<LockOutlined style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
                                placeholder="Enter Password" />)}
                            </Form.Item>
                            <hr></hr>
                            <div style= {{display:'flex',justifyContent:'center'}}>
                                <Button key="submit" type="primary" loading={this.state.loginLoading} onClick={this.onLogin.bind(this)}>Login</Button>            
                            </div>
                        </Card>
                    </div>
                }
                </div>
        );
    }
}
export default  withRouter(Form.create({ name: 'register' })(Login));
```

In latest v4 of ANTJS, they removed `Form.create` and `getFieldDecorator` and made simple
I used this command to migrate

```
npx -p @ant-design/codemod-v4 antd4-codemod src/Login.js
```

Output I Got:

```
Transform v3-Icon-to-v4-Icon
Processing 1 files... 
Spawning 1 workers...
Sending 1 files to free worker...
 SKIP src/screens/Login.js
All done. 
Results: 
0 errors
0 unmodified
1 skipped
0 ok
Time elapsed: 1.243seconds 
Transform v3-Modal-method-with-icon-to-v4
Processing 1 files... 
Spawning 1 workers...
Sending 1 files to free worker...
 SKIP src/screens/Login.js
All done. 
Results: 
0 errors
0 unmodified
1 skipped
0 ok
Time elapsed: 1.214seconds 
Transform v3-component-with-string-icon-props-to-v4
Processing 1 files... 
Spawning 1 workers...
Sending 1 files to free worker...
 SKIP src/screens/Login.js
All done. 
Results: 
0 errors
0 unmodified
1 skipped
0 ok
Time elapsed: 1.306seconds 
Transform v3-Component-to-compatible
Processing 1 files... 
Spawning 1 workers...
Sending 1 files to free worker...
 SKIP src/screens/Login.js
All done. 
Results: 
0 errors
0 unmodified
1 skipped
0 ok
Time elapsed: 1.166seconds 
Transform v3-LocaleProvider-to-v4-ConfigProvider
Processing 1 files... 
Spawning 1 workers...
Sending 1 files to free worker...
 SKIP src/screens/Login.js
All done. 
Results: 
0 errors
0 unmodified
1 skipped
0 ok
Time elapsed: 1.150seconds 
Transform v3-typings-to-compatible
Processing 1 files... 
Spawning 1 workers...
Sending 1 files to free worker...
 SKIP src/screens/Login.js
All done. 
Results: 
0 errors
0 unmodified
1 skipped
0 ok
Time elapsed: 1.097seconds 
----------- antd4 dependencies alert -----------

It's recommended to install or upgrade these dependencies to ensure working well with antd4

> package.json file:  /home/paulsteven/temp-data-filters/sec_data-filters/flax-ui/package.json 

* Update antd^4.0.0 in dependencies

----------- Thanks for using @ant-design/codemod 1.0.2 -----------
```

The above is the result I got. The Code doesn't get changed.  I can do this manual regarding the procedure they provided in their docs. But there is lot of files for me to Change. Help me to upgrade my code to latest v4 of ANTJS automatically.

Comment: I don't think they will be fully migrate your code automatically with there tool, as I understood from a quick read with there v4 doc we need to do something manually. like the icon, we need to import the type based icon component instead of type attribute with icon compoennt.

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behaviour - it is simple enough for the codemod operation to change an import from `import { Form } from 'antd'` to `import { Form } from '@ant-design/compatible'`, but this is just to keep your code functional - it would be considerably harder (and riskier) to implement a service to change the functionality of everyone's code base (I'm sure the ant team would have done something like this if it was easy to do so).

TLDR: Unfortunately that's intended - you have to do change it yourself.